# All arsenic not in the ground is magically removed. What effect would that have?

Tags: science-based, magic, chemistry, element

The land of Koyokuni has been depopulated of people and their domesticated animals for many years, and had been sown with ergot spores, venomous insects, large, aggressive venomous birds and even magical combat automata programmed to kill any intruders, but those sowing the land with these area denial measures also left behind arsenic in Koyokuni's oil lamps and candles, so that if they were ever used, they would poison those nearby.

A group of magicians, including the one who originally ordered the area-denial measures have come in and have cleared them all out, recalling the combat automata, destroying the ergot spores with magic, killing all the venomous critters, and most importantly for this question: they have removed all arsenic that isn't in the ground.

My question is:  What effect would removing pretty much every atom of Arsenic which isn't in the ground throughout the entire unpopulated rennaissance-tech-level land of Koyokuni have?

Don't worry about the plants and animals, I'm concerned about structural or chemical changes to anything that might contain bound Arsenic, that might have been made by rennaissance-level humans.

Comment: The fact that it’s rennaisance-levels of technology is a good thing, that means you probably won’t have lots of people suddenly dying because all the gallium arsenide based electronic components (found in almost all modern wireless communication systems and radar systems) suddenly stop working.

Comment: Would this include any surviving stores of food or animal feed? Arsenic *is* an essential trace element for birds and probably for mammals, though this would only be a problem if they're subsisting entirely off of stored food for an extended time.

Comment: Additionally, destroying the ergot spores will prevent it from spreading, but grain could still contain the alkaloids that cause ergotism.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff The land is depopulated, and there are no foodstuffs left.  Clearing out the area-denial weapons was intended to make the place safe for later repopulation.

Comment: Red, orange, and yellow LEDs would stop working: [gallium arsenide phosphide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallium_arsenide_phosphide). But not the blue ones, unfortunately. Traffic lights would suddenly cause chaos at junctions.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Since there were no LEDs of any variety in the renaissance era, much less electricity, I don't think that there is going to be any problem with traffic lights.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Many things will go extinct

You said “unpopulated” but not lifeless. So, some things will die including rats, hamsters, minipigs, goats, chicks, and possibly even humans.

**They won’t die immediately.** But you will greatly complicate pregnancy, lactation, and could kill things with vitamin B6 deprivation.

No one knows what biological role arsenic plays in organisms, however [studies clearly show that depriving certain things of arsenic causes problems](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01783629).

The exact answer is simply we don’t know because no one has ever tried depriving people or the billions of other species  of arsenic.

Non-living effects will be minor, as already mentioned. Colors may change and some things will be less durable.

Comment: we do know arsenic has a role in methionine synthesis, so removing it from the food chain would be very bad for basically all animals.   https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jtra.10044 but it would not stay out of the food chain for long if plant roots count as "in the ground"

Comment: It sounds like I might need to remove only *high concentration* Arsenic, then, though there isn't supposed to be much left alive in Koyokuni, since it has been kept in darkness for many years.

Comment: Negative impacts on large life forms count as very speculative. Eg. B6 intake goes up with arsenic exposure in many organisms, and while we don't know why that happens in larger animals, we know that for bacteria that's usually a defensive mechanism. They take in the extra B6 because it neutralizes the negative effects of arsenic. There's a fascinating war between bacteria poisoning each other with, and protecting themselves from, arsenic. High concentrations of arsenic completely mess up methylation - both increasing and decreasing it

Comment: Other B vitamins might be involved - eg. folate - so you could get pregnancy, lactation etc... impacts. In labs, rats, hamsters etc. fed arsenic reducing compounds tend to not grow as large, but they do grow and live. And the evidence for why they're not as large is still ambivalent - could be they're missing some other nutrient, which they would just get more of in the wild. Don't get me wrong - the evidence is nudging towards arsenic being essential, so if you'll speculate, speculate that way, that's where the smart money is

Comment: @MontyWild or, you know, just limit the effect to Koyokuni. Seems like that would be an easier spell to cast

Comment: @NoName That was the idea.  In much of this world, each nation is its own realm, and magic doesn't readily go beyond the borders of a realm.  The spell that affects Koyokuni *won't* affect any other realm.  However, Arsenic deficiency in Koyokuni is an issue to consider.

Comment: Ah okay. It's just that you seem to have "salted the earth" pretty effectively, so I thought there wasn't any life to be affected by arsenic deficiency to begin with

Answer (score 12):

- Anything containing copper will age / corrode / wear out faster. Probably the most noticeable effect
- Specifically, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arsenical_bronze will become brittle / easy to shatter and break
- Second most noticeable, some paints will change color and flake/degrade faster - especially vibrant or bright greens (emerald range) and yellows (canary yellow). See https://www.artistsnetwork.com/art-history/arsenic-art-history/ - lose their shine, become more like shades of gray or brown, etc...
- Some bricks and brick work will become more fragile and degrade (but not very fast). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick and the use of arsenic-iron sludge as a strengthening agent in bricks
- Arsenic will show up in many kinds of traditional pottery, and pots will become more brittle too. Also, crushed, glazed pottery is sometimes used in mortar or early forms of concrete, which could also degrade. See eg https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27392578/ - again, not super fast to be noticed

Comment: I'm not sure what your context is here, but if you want to get a bit speculative, you could have certain marine life forms be impacted too. See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0308814612001677

Comment: Some algae and other marine plants accumulate arsenic, and some animals eat it and convert it to bio-available forms. It's unclear if this is a process that detoxifies things, or if there's an actual biological dependence on arsenic in some animals. There could also be a period of animals being sick (say diarrhea and gas for a couple of days) because the bioavailable arsenic degrades into oils/fats which then get processed/passed

Comment: "Although there is no known biological function of arsenic ... it was found that arsenic deprivation had little effect on growth in rats fed adequate methionine. ... fed suboptimal methionine, arsenic deprivation resulted in a significant reduction in body weight. Other studies showed that feeding methyl depletors caused severe signs of arsenic deprivation ... it was found that alteration in methionine status or methyl metabolism affected signs of arsenic deprivation ... arsenic has a physiological role affecting methionine metabolism" https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jtra.10044

Answer (score 0):

Wearing green will stop being unlucky.

This superstition arose from the consequences of skin absorption of arsenic by those who wore green. The green dyes contained arsenic.